How does the $S$-matrix look like for composite particle (possibly inelastic) scattering?
I've just started learning about $S$-matrices in quantum mechanics and I'm a bit confused by how the $S$-matrix would look like for the scattering of composite particles.
E.g., for a simple 1D problem ($H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V(x)$ with $V(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \pm\infty$ fast enough), the $S$-matrix is just a 2x2 matrix relating the incoming and outgoing waves ($\psi=e^{\pm ikx}$) from the left and from the right.
However, suppose I took an object composed of two "elementary" particles, held together by a potential $u(x_2 - x_1)$ and scattered it on a 1D potential barrier. I.e., the Hamiltonian now is
$$H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_1} \frac{d^2}{dx_1^2}-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_2} \frac{d^2}{dx_2^2}+V(x_1)+V(x_2)+u(x_2-x_1).$$
Now, after the scattering event, many different things could have happened - the object might end up in an excited state. Or it might fall apart completely, with particle 1 reflected and particle 2 transmitted. (And the initial conditions are more complicated, since the object could be in any energy level of the potential $u(x_2-x_1)$.)
My question is - how would the $S$-matrix look like in this case?
In the limit $x\to\pm\infty$, I can still decompose the wavefunction as
$$\psi_{nk}(x_1,x_2) = \phi_n(x_1-x_2) e^{\pm ik(x_1+x_2)/2},$$
a composite particle travelling with momentum $k$, where $\phi_n$ is an eigenfunction of $H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2}{dx^2}+u(x)$. I assume the $S$-matrix would then relate states with constant energy, i.e. the same $E_{tot} = E_n + \frac {\hbar^2 k^2} {4m}$ (since the total mass is $2m$). But how would reactive scattering, where the composite object breaks apart, be described?
